# Laravel middleware not restricting route access

Tags: php, laravel

I created a middleware which allows allows users only if they have a role `client`. 
But when i use the middleware it still let the users to access routes who dont have client role.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    if ($user && $user->role = 'client') {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('home');

}
```

Here is my route. I did the same thing with other middleware which works fine. but not this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){

Route::group(['middleware'=>['client']],function(){

   Route::get('/index',[
'as' => 'index',
'uses' => 'HomeController@showCandidates',
]);
});
});
```

When the role is not client it shouldn't let access the route but it does.

**edit** From alexey's answer I changed my other middleware with == , the question above is solved. But the middleware below restricts me from accessing the route even though my role is interviewer.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    if($user && $user->roles == 'interviewer'){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('home');

}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','interviewer']],function(){

Route::get('/candidates', [
'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
]);
});
```

What is the possible error i am making here. It works fine when `=` is used in interviewer middleware and `==` used in client middleware and not working when done vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're checking the role, change this:

```
$user->role = 'client'
```

To this:

```
$user->role == 'client'
```

Comment: This is another issue and in future please create another question for any new issues, that's how SO works. Regarding your new issue, you have a typo, it should be `role`, but not `roles`

Answer (score 3):

I found a nice convention called **Yoda Conditions** to avoid such issues in the future.

in your

```
if ($user && $user->role = 'client') {
    return $next($request);
}
```

Instead doing

```
$user->role == 'client'
```

do

```
'client' == $user->role
```

The usefulness of this is if you mistakenly type `=` instead of `==`, `$user->role` doesn't get assigned the value `client`. So you could avoid unexpected behaviors.

Read more about [To Yoda or Not to Yoda](https://knowthecode.io/yoda-conditions-yoda-not-yoda)

Comment: In PHP 7, trying to assign a variable to a string would result in a parse error making this an excellent solution.  It makes it impossible to make the mistake of using `=` in conditionals.